# How to know Multiple TLS versions of the host using python?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, socket.io, request, tls1.2

I am using the below method to get the TLS version of the host

```
ssock.version()
```

But , it is giving only one version of the host.How can I get multiple supported version of the host ?